# How can I automatically display the help on command line arguments error?

Tags: python, argparse

Currently when I enter invalid options or omit positional arguments, argparse kicks me back to the prompt and displays the usage for my app.

This is ok, but I would rather automatically display the full help listing (that explains the options, etc.) than require the user to type

```
./myscript.py -h
```

Comment: see also this SO question for more info: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042452][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042452

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/argparse-users/browse_thread/thread/2dacd5fed110bd0c?pli=1) over at Google groups has the following code snippet which seems to do the trick (modified slightly).

```
class DefaultHelpParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def error(self, message):
        sys.stderr.write('error: %s\n' % message)
        self.print_help()
        sys.exit(2)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to use `self.print_help(sys.stderr)` here?

Comment: If it's not entirely clear, you should use `DefaultHelpParser` instead of how you usually use `argparse.ArgumentParser` after creating this class

Answer (score 34):

To print help you might want to use: `print_help` function on `ArgumentParser` instance

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
(...)
parser.print_help()
```

To print help message on error you need to create own subclass of `ArgumentParser` instance, that overrides `error()` method; for example:

```
class MyParser(argparse.ArgumentParser): 
   def error(self, message):
      sys.stderr.write('error: %s\n' % message)
      self.print_help()
      sys.exit(2)
```

and then use it:

```
parser = MyParser()
```

When this parser encounters unparseable argument line it will print help.

Answer (score 4):

I just fixed this same problem myself using the following syntax:

```
parser = ArgumentParser()
... add arguments ...
parser.usage = parser.format_help()
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: The simplicity is enticing, but note that it makes '-h' print the help info twice

Answer (score 3):

Suppress printing of usage with `usage=argparse.SUPPRESS`. Then catch the SystemExit exception that ArgumentParser raises on error, print the help, and exit by raising the exception again.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage=argparse.SUPPRESS)
parser.add_argument(...)
try:
    args = parser.parse_args()
except SystemExit:
    parser.print_help()
    raise
```

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Read :)

Comment: Now when you invoke the program with `-h`, it prints the help twice.

Comment: I wanted to print both the usage and the help message, so I removed the `usage=argparse.SUPPRESS` option when I created the parser object, but I added `arp.usage=argparse.SUPPRESS` on the first line after `except SystemExit:` so the usage isn't printed twice.

Comment: To prevent double help printing I changed code like this: ```except SystemExit as e: if e.code != 0: parser.print_help()
```

Answer (score 0):

You, also, can print help without using a class or exception:

```py
def _error(parser):
    def wrapper(interceptor):
        parser.print_help()

        sys.exit(-1)

    return wrapper

def _args_get(args=sys.argv[1:]):
    parser = argparser.ArgumentParser()

    parser.error = _error(parser)

    parser.add_argument(...)
    ...
```

. Just wrap `ArgumentParser.error` function in your and intercept `message` argument. I answered, there, earlier:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60714163/10152015