# Display help message with Python argparse when script is called without any arguments

Tags: python, argparse

Assume I have a program that uses `argparse` to process command line arguments/options. The following will print the 'help' message:

```
./myprogram -h
```

or:

```
./myprogram --help
```

But, if I run the script without any arguments whatsoever, it doesn't do anything. What I want it to do is to display the usage message when it is called with no arguments. How is that done?

Answer (score 387, accepted):

This answer comes from Steven Bethard [on Google groups](http://groups.google.com/group/argparse-users/browse_thread/thread/2dacd5fed110bd0c?pli=1). I'm reposting it here to make it easier for people without a Google account to access.

You can override the default behavior of the `error` method:

```
import argparse
import sys

class MyParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def error(self, message):
        sys.stderr.write('error: %s\n' % message)
        self.print_help()
        sys.exit(2)

parser = MyParser()
parser.add_argument('foo', nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

---

Note that the above solution will print the help message whenever the `error`
method is triggered. For example, `test.py --blah` will print the help message
too if `--blah` isn't a valid option.

If you want to print the help message only if no arguments are supplied on the
command line, then perhaps this is still the easiest way:

```
import argparse
import sys

parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('foo', nargs='+')
if len(sys.argv)==1:
    parser.print_help(sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)
args=parser.parse_args()
```

---

Note that `parser.print_help()` prints to stdout by default. As [init_js suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042452/display-help-message-with-python-argparse-when-script-is-called-without-any-argu/4042861?noredirect=1#comment84996345_4042861), use `parser.print_help(sys.stderr)` to print to stderr.

Comment: In the second solution I use `parser.print_usage()` in place of `parser.print_help()` -- the help message includes usage but it's more verbose.

Comment: I would have voted for the second part of the answer, but overriding `error()` seems a terrible idea to me. It serves a different purpose, it's not designed for printing a friendly usage or help.

Comment: @Peterino - the override is occurring in a child class, so this shouldn't be a problem.  It's explicit.

Comment: In the second part, consider using `sys.exit(0)` to get the same exit status as with `./myprogram -h`

Comment: `sys.exit(0)` indicates the program ended successfully. `sys.exit(1)` indicates the program ended with a failure.

Comment: If you want to get the help message as a string instead of printing it directly: `help_message = parser.format_help()`.

Comment: `print_help()` and `print_usage()` both can take a stream as a parameter. if you wanted to be more in line with the rest of the error handling in argparse, on an error, one could do `parser.print_help(sys.stderr)`. I think that's good user interface etiquette.

Comment: I think sometimes the user could take input from stdin,  In such case I would write the could this way:  `    if len(sys.argv) == 1 and sys.stdin.isatty():
        parser.print_help(sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)`

Comment: @Peterino: `error()` is very literally designed to print a friendly usage message.

Comment: Subclassing ArgumentParser and handling the help printing in `parse_args()` would seem like the cleaner solution...

Answer (score 95):

Instead of writing a class, a try/except can be used instead

```
try:
    options = parser.parse_args()
except:
    parser.print_help()
    sys.exit(0)
```

The upside is that the workflow is clearer and you don't need a stub class. The downside is that the first 'usage' line is printed twice.

This will need at least one mandatory argument. With no mandatory arguments, providing zero args on the commandline is valid.

Comment: me too, I prefer this to the accepted answer. Adding a class is overkilled for printing help when the arguments are unexpected. Let the excellent module argparse handle error cases for you.

Comment: This code prints help 2 times if `-h` flag is used, and unnecessary prints help if `--version` flag is used. To mitigate those problems  you can check error type like this:
`except SystemExit as err: if err.code == 2: parser.print_help()`

Comment: Why not just catch `AttributeError`? Should be no problem with `-h` or `--version` flag.

Comment: Another downside is that bare except can catch all sorts of exceptions including keyboard interrupt

Answer (score 74):

The cleanest solution will be to manually pass default argument if none were given on the command line:

```
parser.parse_args(args=None if sys.argv[1:] else ['--help'])
```

Complete example:

```
import argparse, sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--host', default='localhost', help='Host to connect to')
# parse arguments
args = parser.parse_args(args=None if sys.argv[1:] else ['--help'])

# use your args
print("connecting to {}".format(args.host))
```

This will print complete help (not short usage) if called w/o arguments.

Comment: I think this is the nicest of all listed here!

Comment: By far the cleanest solution. It works!

Comment: Indeed, clean and good solution

Comment: Perhaps `args=(sys.argv[1:] or ['--help'])` would be even shorter

Comment: I noticed that calling `parse_args("-h")` seems to automatically do a `sys.exit()` call.

Answer (score 47):

With argparse you could use `ArgumentParser.print_usage()`:

```py
parser.argparse.ArgumentParser()
# parser.add_args here

# sys.argv includes a list of elements starting with the program
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    parser.print_usage()
    sys.exit(1)
```

> [Printing help](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.print_usage)
>
> `ArgumentParser.print_usage(file=None)`
>
> Print a brief description of how the `ArgumentParser` should be invoked on the command line. If `file` is `None`, `sys.stdout` is assumed.

Comment: This must come _before_ the call to `parser.parse_args()`

Answer (score 33):

If you associate default functions for (sub)parsers, as is mentioned under [`add_subparsers`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers), you can simply add it as the default action:

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.set_defaults(func=lambda x: parser.print_usage())
args = parser.parse_args()
args.func(args)
```

Add the try-except if you raise exceptions due to missing positional arguments.

Comment: This answer is so underrated. Simple and works very well with sub-parsers.

Comment: Great answer! The only change I made was using a lambda without parameter.

Comment: @boh717 In order for that to work you would have to be calling `args.func()` without any arguments, whereas the pattern used here (and also in the argparse documentation) is to pass `args` itself to the function.

Answer (score 24):

If you have arguments that must be specified for the script to run - use the **required** parameter for ArgumentParser as shown below:-

```py
parser.add_argument('--foo', required=True)
```

parse_args() will report an error if the script is run without any arguments.

Comment: This is the simplest solution and will work with invalid options specified as well.

Comment: Agreed. I think it's always better to leverage the built-in abilities of the argument parser then to write an additional handler of some kind.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the actual question. The OP wishes for a help message to print if no arguments are given. This answer involves adding in a required optional argument, which is not what was asked. At best, this will only print a usage message.

Answer (score 11):

Throwing my version into the pile here:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
args = parser.parse_args()
if not vars(args):
    parser.print_help()
    parser.exit(1)
```

You may notice the `parser.exit` - I mainly do it like that because it saves an import line if that was the only reason for `sys` in the file...

Comment: Unfortunately parser.parse_args() will exit if a positional argument is missing. So this only works when using optional arguments.

Comment: @MarcelWilson, it does indeed - good catch! I'll have a think about how to change it.

Comment: `not vars(args)` may not work when arguments have `default` method.

Answer (score 8):

There are a pair of one-liners with `sys.argv[1:]` (a very common Python's idiom to refer the command line arguments, being `sys.argv[0]` the script's name) that can do the job.

The first one is self-explanatory, clean and pythonic:

```
args = parser.parse_args(None if sys.argv[1:] else ['-h'])
```

The second one is a little hackier. Combining the previously evaluated fact that an empty list is `False` with the `True == 1` and `False == 0` equivalences you get this:

```
args = parser.parse_args([None, ['-h']][not sys.argv[1:]])
```

Maybe too many brackets, but pretty clear if a previous argument selection was made.

```
_, *av = sys.argv
args = parser.parse_args([None, ['-h']][not av])
```

Answer (score 6):

Most of the answers here required another module, such as `sys`, to be imported or were using optional arguments. I wanted to discover an answer that used only `argparse`, worked with required arguments, and if possible worked without catching exceptions. I ended up with the following:

```
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':

    arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
    arg_parser.add_argument('input_file', type=str, help='The path to the input file.')
    arg_parser.add_argument('output_file', type=str, help='The path to the output file.')
    arg_parser.add_argument('-h','--help', action='store_true', help='show this help message and exit')
    arg_parser.usage = arg_parser.format_help()
    args = arg_parser.parse_args()
```

The main idea was to use the `format_help` function in order to provide the help string to the usage statement. Setting `add_help` to `False` in the call to `ArgumentParser()` prevents the help statement from printing twice in certain circumstances. However, I had to create an argument for the optional help argument that mimicked the typical help message once it was set to `False` in order to display the optional help argument in the help message. The action is set to `store_true` in the help argument to prevent the help message from filling in a value like `HELP` for the parameter when it prints the help message.

Answer (score 5):

```
parser.print_help()
parser.exit()
```

---

The `parser.exit` method also accept a `status` (returncode), and a `message` value (include a trailing newline yourself!).

an opinionated example,
:)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

""" Example argparser based python file
"""

import argparse

ARGP = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description=__doc__,
    formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter,
)
ARGP.add_argument('--example', action='store_true', help='Example Argument')


def main(argp=None):
    if argp is None:
        argp = ARGP.parse_args()  # pragma: no cover

    if 'soemthing_went_wrong' and not argp.example:
        ARGP.print_help()
        ARGP.exit(status=64, message="\nSomething went wrong, --example condition was not set\n")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()  # pragma: no cover
```

Example calls:

```
$ python3 ~/helloworld.py; echo $?
usage: helloworld.py [-h] [--example]

 Example argparser based python file

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --example   Example Argument

Something went wrong, --example condition was not set
64
$ python3 ~/helloworld.py --example; echo $?
0
```

Answer (score 2):

So for a really simple answer.  Most of the time with argparse you are checking to see if parameters are set anyway, to call a function that does something.

If no parameters, just else out at the end and print the help.  Simple and works.

```
import argparse
import sys
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument("--holidays", action='store_true')
group.add_argument("--people", action='store_true')

args=parser.parse_args()
if args.holidays:
    get_holidays()
elif args.people:
    get_people()
else:
    parser.print_help(sys.stderr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it, if you need something flexible where you want to display help if specific params are passed, none at all or more than 1 conflicting arg:

```
import argparse
import sys

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--days', required=False,  help="Check mapped inventory that is x days old", default=None)
    parser.add_argument('-e', '--event', required=False, action="store", dest="event_id",
                        help="Check mapped inventory for a specific event", default=None)
    parser.add_argument('-b', '--broker', required=False, action="store", dest="broker_id",
                        help="Check mapped inventory for a broker", default=None)
    parser.add_argument('-k', '--keyword', required=False, action="store", dest="event_keyword",
                        help="Check mapped inventory for a specific event keyword", default=None)
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--product', required=False, action="store", dest="product_id",
                        help="Check mapped inventory for a specific product", default=None)
    parser.add_argument('-m', '--metadata', required=False, action="store", dest="metadata",
                        help="Check mapped inventory for specific metadata, good for debugging past tix", default=None)
    parser.add_argument('-u', '--update', required=False, action="store_true", dest="make_updates",
                        help="Update the event for a product if there is a difference, default No", default=False)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    days = args.days
    event_id = args.event_id
    broker_id = args.broker_id
    event_keyword = args.event_keyword
    product_id = args.product_id
    metadata = args.metadata
    make_updates = args.make_updates

    no_change_counter = 0
    change_counter = 0

    req_arg = bool(days) + bool(event_id) + bool(broker_id) + bool(product_id) + bool(event_keyword) + bool(metadata)
    if not req_arg:
        print("Need to specify days, broker id, event id, event keyword or past tickets full metadata")
        parser.print_help()
        sys.exit()
    elif req_arg != 1:
        print("More than one option specified. Need to specify only one required option")
        parser.print_help()
        sys.exit()

    # Processing logic here ...
```

Cheers!

Comment: I think you would be much easier use subparsers or mutually_exclusive_group

Answer (score 1):

I like to keep things as simple as possible, this works great:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
Description = """Tool description"""
Epilog  = """toolname.py -a aflag -b bflag  with these combined it does blah"""
arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
    description=Description, 
    epilog=Epilog,
)
    try:
        if len(sys.argv) == 1:
            arg_parser.print_help()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

This is how I start all my tools as its always good to include some examples

Comment: The best answer :)

Answer (score 1):

When call `add_subparsers` method save the first positional argument to `dest=` and check value after argparse has been initialized, like this:

`subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='command')`

And just check this this variable:

```py
if not args.command:
    parser.print_help()
    parser.exit(1)  # If exit() - exit code will be zero (no error)
```

Full example:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

""" doc """

import argparse
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='command',
                                   help='List of commands')

list_parser = subparsers.add_parser('list',
                                    help='List contents')
list_parser.add_argument('dir', action='store',
                         help='Directory to list')

create_parser = subparsers.add_parser('create',
                                      help='Create a directory')
create_parser.add_argument('dirname', action='store',
                           help='New directory to create')
create_parser.add_argument('--read-only', default=False, action='store_true',
                           help='Set permissions to prevent writing to the directory')

args = parser.parse_args()

if not args.command:
    parser.print_help()
    parser.exit(1)

print(vars(args))  # For debug
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach is a lot more elegant than most others. Instead of overriding `error()`, you can control the behaviour a lot more precisely by wrapping the `parse_args()` method:

```py
import sys
import argparse


HelpFlags = ('help', '--help', '-h', '/h', '?', '/?', )


class ArgParser (argparse.ArgumentParser):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kws):
        super().__init__(*args, **kws)
    
    def parse_args(self, args=None, namespace=None):
        
        if args is None:
            args = sys.argv[1:]
        
        if len(args) < 1 or (args[0].lower() in HelpFlags):
            self.print_help(sys.stderr)
            sys.exit()
        
        return super().parse_args(args, namespace)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your positional arguments with nargs, and check if positional args are empty.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('file', nargs='?')
args = parser.parse_args()
if not args.file:
    parser.print_help()
```

Reference [Python nargs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#nargs)

Answer (score 0):

If your command is something where a user needs to choose some action, then use a mutually exclusive group **with required=True**.

This is kind of an extension to the answer given by pd321.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument("--batch", action='store', type=int,  metavar='pay_id')
group.add_argument("--list", action='store_true')
group.add_argument("--all", action='store_true', help='check all payments')

args=parser.parse_args()

if args.batch:
    print('batch {}'.format(args.batch))

if args.list:
    print('list')

if args.all:
    print('all')
```

Output:

> $ python3 a_test.py 
>   usage: a_test.py [-h] (--batch pay_id | --list | --all) 
>   a_test.py: error: one of the arguments --batch --list --all is required

This only give the basic help.  And some of the other answers will give you the full help.   But at least your users know they can do **-h**

Answer (score 0):

This isn't good (also, because intercepts all errors), but:

```py
def _error(parser):
    def wrapper(interceptor):
        parser.print_help()

        sys.exit(-1)

    return wrapper

def _args_get(args=sys.argv[1:]):
    parser = argparser.ArgumentParser()

    parser.error = _error(parser)

    parser.add_argument(...)
    ...
```

[Here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/276eb67c29d05a93fbc22eea5470282e73700d20/Lib/argparse.py#L2374) is definition of the `error` function of the `ArgumentParser` class.

As you see, the following signature takes two arguments. However, functions outside the class know nothing about first argument `self`, because, roughly speaking, this argument is for the class.

```py
def _error(self, message):
    self.print_help()

    sys.exit(-1)

def _args_get(args=sys.argv[1:]):
    parser = argparser.ArgumentParser()

    parser.error = _error
    ...
```

will output:

```
"AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'print_help'"
```

You can pass `parser` (`self`) in `_error` function, by calling it:

```py
def _error(self, message):
    self.print_help()

    sys.exit(-1)

def _args_get(args=sys.argv[1:]):
    parser = argparser.ArgumentParser()

    parser.error = _error(parser)
    ...
```

But if you don't want exit the program right now, return it:

```py
def _error(parser):
    def wrapper():
        parser.print_help()

        sys.exit(-1)

    return wrapper
```

Nonetheless, `parser` doesn't know that it has been modified. Thus, when an error occurs, it will print the cause of it (by the way, it's a localized translation). So intercept it:

```py
def _error(parser):
    def wrapper(interceptor):
        parser.print_help()

        sys.exit(-1)

    return wrapper
```

Now, when an error occurs, `parser` will print the cause of it, and you'll intercept it, look at it, and... throw out.