# How do I specify two required arguments, including a subcommand, using 'argparse'?

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

Is there a way to specify two required arguments in [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse), one that corresponds to a subcommand, and another that is required by all subcommands.

The closest I can manage seems to be with

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='', dest='command',  metavar='COMMAND', title='required arguments',
                                   description='two arguments are required')
parser.add_argument('config', metavar='CONFIG', action='store', help='the config to use')

cmda_parser = subparsers.add_parser('cmdA',  help='a first command')
cmdb_parser = subparsers.add_parser('cmdB',  help='the second operation')
cmdc_parser = subparsers.add_parser('cmdC',  help='yet another thing')

print(parser.parse_args())
```

which gives

```
usage: enigma.py [-h] COMMAND ... CONFIG

positional arguments:
  CONFIG      the config to use

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit

required arguments:
  two arguments are required

  COMMAND
    cmdA      a first command
    cmdB      the second operation
    cmdC      yet another thing
```

and help for subcommands that does not show `CONFIG`; but what I want is

```
usage: enigma.py [-h] COMMAND CONFIG

required arguments:
  two arguments are required

  COMMAND
    cmdA      a first command
    cmdB      the second operation
    cmdC      yet another thing

  CONFIG      the config to use

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

and help for each subcommand that does show `CONFIG`, eg.

```
usage: enigma.py cmdA CONFIG [-h] 

    required arguments:

      CONFIG      the config to use

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

is there any way to accomplish this?

How to I specific *two* required arguments, one of which is a subcommand, with the second "propagated" to each subcommand as a required argument?

Comment: Have you tried defining CONFIG first?

Comment: @hpaulj: CONFIG goes after COMMAND.

Comment: Then define it for each subparser.

Comment: @hpaulj: The whole point of the question is to see if that can be avoided.

Comment: What's the purpose of avoiding that?  Would it make the code clearer, or just shorter?  There's no 'propagation' mechanism in `argparse`.

Comment: @hpaulj: Both, of course.

Comment: You may need to resort to a custom  `usage` parameter(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsers can "inherit" arguments from another parser, using the `parents` attribute.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

# Put common subparser arguments here. Each sub parser will have
# its own -h option, so disable it on the shared base.
subbase = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
subbase.add_argument('config', metavar='CONFIG', action='store', help='the config to use')

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='', dest='command',  metavar='COMMAND', title='required arguments',
                                   description='two arguments are required')

# Add subbase to the parent list for each subparser.
cmda_parser = subparsers.add_parser('cmdA', parents=[subbase],  help='a first command')
cmdb_parser = subparsers.add_parser('cmdB', parents=[subbase], help='the second operation')
cmdc_parser = subparsers.add_parser('cmdC', parents=[subbase], help='yet another thing')

print(parser.parse_args())
```

Comment: Getting close, I think. But this doesn't list `CONFIG` as one of the two required arguments when help is asked for without specifying an argument.

Comment: You have to use `script.py cmdA -h` to see `CONFIG` listed as an argument. It's an argument of the subparser, not the main parser.

Comment: That gets into a different issue - that none of the subparser arguments are displayed in the main parser help.  Each parser (and that includes the main one) only displays its own arguments.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094215/argparse-subparser-monolithic-help-output is one of several SO questions about displaying the help for both a main parser and subparsers.

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for, but it illustrates why argparse prevents me from doing it. This is one of the least thought-through Python APIs I've used.

Answer (score 0):

With the parser that you defined, `COMMAND` and `CONFIG` are both required.  Try for example

```
python myprog cmdA
```

You should get a missed argument error.  On newer version it will be explicit

```
0826:~/mypy$ python3.5 stack33463052.py cmdA 
usage: stack33463052.py [-h] COMMAND ... CONFIG
stack33463052.py: error: the following arguments are required: CONFIG
```

But, yes, `COMMAND` does not appear in the subparser's help.  That's because the subparse knows nothing about it.  It was defined for the main parser.

If I move `CONFIG` definition to before the `subparsers` creation, I get:

```
0833:~/mypy$ python stack33463052.py tst cmdA -h
usage: stack33463052.py CONFIG cmdA [-h]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Now `CONFIG` appears in the usage.  That's because the code knows about this argument when the subparser is defined.  But - I had to include a value for `CONFIG` when seeking this help.

---

(edit)
`CONFIG` appears in the `cmdA` usage because it was added to it's `prog` attribute when the parser was created:

```
 print(cmda_parser.prog)
 'stack33463052.py CONFIG cmdA'
```

But that `prog` is not modified if arguments are later added to `parser`.

---

In the following, `cmdA` is taken as an argument to `CONFIG`, not `COMMAND`, and thus I get the default main parser help.

```
0833:~/mypy$ python stack33463052.py cmdA -h
usage: stack33463052.py [-h] CONFIG COMMAND ...

positional arguments:
  CONFIG      the config to use

optional arguments:
...
```

To the main parser both `CONFIG` and `COMMAND` are required positionals.  There's nothing special about `COMMAND`, except that it has 3 defined `choices`.

Defining `CONFIG` for each of the subparsers might be the best choice.  It requires more typing, but it will be displayed in the right help.  If conceptually it is linked more closely with the commands than the main parser, then it needs to defined with them.  That fact that all commands need it isn't that important.

In general, when using subparsers, it is best to use optionals for main parser values like vebosity and logging, and define the rest in the subparers.  It keeps the division of effort between the parsers cleaner.  I can elaborate on that if needed.

There's no propagation mechanism.  But I could certainly write a function that would add a common argument to each subparser.

```
def foo(subparsers, *args, **kwargs):
   sub = subparsers.add_parser(*args, **kwargs)
   sub.add_argument('config')
   return sub
```

It can be instructive to run a parser setup in an interactive shell, and examine the objects that each command creates - `parser`, `subparsers`, `cmda_parser`, etc.  The list of arguments (Action objects) that `parser` knows about is in `parser._actions`.

Program clarity and conciseness in the `argparse` module means that `parser` and `cmda_parser` are distinct `ArgumentParser` objects.  One isn't just a mode or method of the other.   The `subparsers` object (an Action subclass) is the only formal link between `parser` and `cmda_parser`.

Also try:

```
parser.print_help() # or parser.print_usage()
cmda_parser.print_help()
```

This helps show that the `help` for the 2 parsers is independent.