# How can I add more subparsers to an argpare parser?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse, subparsers

If my code calls a function which returns an `ArgumentParser` that already has some subparsers defined, how can I add more subparsers?

I'd like to do something this:

```
parser_with_subparsers = build_parser()
additional_subparsers = parser_with_subparsers.add_subparsers()
extra_subparser = additional_subparsers.add_parser("extra", help="extra help"))
```

But when I attempt that in the interpreter:

```
>>> parser_with_subparsers = build_parser()
>>> additional_subparsers = parser_with_subparsers.add_subparsers()
usage: [-h] {original_subparser} ...
: error: cannot have multiple subparser arguments
```

Note that I do not have access to the internals of the `build_parser()` function.

The only solution I can think of is using `parents`, but this has the side effect of grouping the subparsers in a strange way:

```
>>> child_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[build_parser()])
>>> additional_subparsers = child_parser.add_subparsers()
>>> extra_subparser = additional_subparsers.add_parser("extra", help="extra help")
>>> extra_subparser2 = additional_subparsers.add_parser("extra2", help="extra2 help")
>>> child_parser.print_help()
usage: [-h] {original_subparser} ... {extra,extra2} ...

positional arguments:
  {original_subparser}
    original_subparser  original_subparser help
  {extra,extra2}
    extra               extra help
    extra2              extra2 help

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
```

The reason I want to do this is that I want to add extra 'commands' to an `Argument Parser` that I have inherited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What kind of behavior are you expecting from the added subparsers?

```
sp = parser.add_subparsers(...)
```

`add_subparsers` creates a positional argument of `_SubParsersAction` class, and makes a note of it in a `parser._subparsers` attribute.  It raises that error if that attribute has already been set.  `sp` is that `Action` object.

Logically it doesn't make sense to have more than one 'subparsers' action.  When the main parser encounters of a subparser command, it delegates the parsing to that subparser.  Apart from some cleanup error checking the main parser does not resume parsing.  So it couldn't handle a second subparser command.

(the terminology for what `add_subparsers` creates and what `add_parser` does can be a confusing.  One is a positional argument/Action, the other a parser (instance of `ArgumentParser`).

It should be possible to add new parsers to an existing `subparsers` Action (I'd have to experiment to find a clean way of doing this).  It also possible to add nest subparsers, that is, define `add_subparsers` for a subparser.

---

That `parents` approach bypasses this`multiple subparser arguments` test, probably because it doesn't set the `parser._subparsers` attribute the first time (when copying Actions from the parent).  So that in effect creates two `subparser arguments`.  That's what the `help` shows.  But my guess is that the parsing will not be meaningful.  It will still expect 'original_subparser' and not look for 'extra' or 'extra2'.

The `parents` mechanism is not robust.  There are straight forward uses of it, but it's easily broken.

---

```
In [2]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='main')
In [3]: a1 = parser.add_argument('--foo')
In [4]: parser._subparsers    # initial value None

In [5]: sp = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd')
In [6]: parser._subparsers    # new non-None value
Out[6]: <argparse._ArgumentGroup at 0xaf780f0c>
```

The `sp` object, an Action subclass:

```
In [8]: sp
Out[8]: _SubParsersAction(option_strings=[], dest='cmd', nargs='A...', const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=OrderedDict(), help=None, metavar=None)
In [9]: sp1 = sp.add_parser('cmd1')
```

`sp` is an Action (positional argument); `sp1` is a parser.

```
In [10]: parser.print_help()
usage: main [-h] [--foo FOO] {cmd1} ...

positional arguments:
  {cmd1}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --foo FOO
```

The `_actions`  attribute is a list of actions.  Note the `help`, and `foo`

```
In [12]: parser._subparsers._actions
Out[12]: 
[_HelpAction(option_strings=['-h', '--help'], dest='help',...),
 _StoreAction(option_strings=['--foo'], dest='foo',....),
 _SubParsersAction(option_strings=[], dest='cmd', ...]
```

So the last item in this list is the `sp` object

```
In [13]: parser._subparsers._actions[-1]
Out[13]: _SubParsersAction(option_strings=[], dest='cmd', nargs='A...', const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=OrderedDict([('cmd1', ArgumentParser(prog='main cmd1', usage=None, description=None, formatter_class=<class 'argparse.HelpFormatter'>, conflict_handler='error', add_help=True))]), help=None, metavar=None)
```

So we can added a new subparser with

```
In [14]: parser._subparsers._actions[-1].add_parser('extra')
...
In [15]: parser.print_help()
usage: main [-h] [--foo FOO] {cmd1,extra} ...

positional arguments:
  {cmd1,extra}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help    show this help message and exit
  --foo FOO
```

So if you want just add `extra` and `extra2` to `original_subparser`, this should work.

So as long as we don't try further `parser.add_argument(...)` grabbing the last `_actions` item should work.  If it isn't the last, we'd have to do a more sophisticate search.

Judging from my rep change, someone found this earlier exploration of the `_subparsers` attribute:

[How to obtain argparse subparsers from a parent parser (to inspect defaults)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43688450/how-to-obtain-argparse-subparsers-from-a-parent-parser-to-inspect-defaults)

Comment: Thank you. I am a bit wary of poking around in the internals of the module, but this indeed does seem like the only way to do it!