# Argparse to show usage help for subcommand

Tags: python, argparse

Consider this `arg_test.py` script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='subcommand help')

# create the parser for subcommand
parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('do-stuff', help='Help for do-stuff subcommand')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

---

With the help for the subcommand I get:

```
./arg_test.py do-stuff -h
usage: arg_test.py do-stuff [-h]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

How can I add some usage description when using `-h`? For example I would like to get:

```
./arg_test.py do-stuff -h
usage: arg_test.py do-stuff [-h]

This subcommand does awsome stuff       << HOW DO I ADD THIS?

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Comment: Did you had a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094215/argparse-subparser-monolithic-help-output

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I think that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094215/argparse-subparser-monolithic-help-output is more complex than what I need and I'm not sure it answers my question. I was hoping for a simple option that I've missed since printing the usage of a subcommand when that subcommand is invoked seems pretty reasonable to me...

Comment: The `add_parser` commend takes the same parameters as `ArgumentParser`, such as `description` and `epilog`.

Comment: @hpaulj indeed `description` is the option I needed - I don't know how I could have missed it... If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

That's an easy one to miss.

The `help=` keyword text will be displayed when the user asks for `--help` in list of available subcommands in the parent (usually top-level) parser help. You generally want to keep this one brief.

If you want to show a more elaborate paragraph of text at the top of the subcommand's help, you can use the `description=` keyword on the call to `add_parser()`

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='subcommand help')

# create the parser for subcommand
parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('do-stuff', 

   # will be shown in the _parent_ parser's `--help` output.
   help='Help for do-stuff subcommand',

   # will be used as the top-level description in the subcommand's help
   # text, where the user generally expects to find the usage.
   description="""
Use this command to do foo. It's awesome stuff ...

There's several modes available, and they're all great.
"""

   # will be displayed at the end of the sub-command help text
   epilog="good luck!"
)
args = parser.parse_args()
```