# python argparse print usage text after description

Tags: python, argparse

Is there a way to print usage text after the description text with python argparse? I have my cmd line argparse working, but i would like to print version info before usage info.

Edit:

```
version: 1.0

usage: blahcmd [-h] [-help] 

some lovely help
```

Comment: Please show us an example of what you want to do.

Comment: One fairly ugly option is to define your own subclass of `HelpFormatter` to pass to the parser with the `formatter_class` option. Your subclass would probably want to override the `_format_usage` method. This isn't entirely recommended, since the interface for defining your own formatting class was never made public.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `argparse` module does not provide any option to add a "prolog". When the help is displayed it *always* start with `usage:`. The best you can do is to customize the usage text adding the version number, using the [`usage`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/argparse.html#usage) parameter when you instantiate the `ArgumentParser`:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage='Any text you want\n')
```

Note that the help will still start with `usage:`.

A dirty workaround that might work is to start the `usage` message with a `\r`:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> usage = '\r{}\nusage: %(prog)s etc.'.format('Version a b'.ljust(len('usage:')))
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage=usage)
>>> parser.parse_args(['-h'])
Version a b
usage:  etc.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

I don't think that this usage of `\r` is portable. There are probably some terminals where this trick doesn't work. I've `ljust`ed the version string to make sure that when the trick works, the whole `usage:` string disappears from string and you don't get things like `v1.2e:` when using short version strings.

Note: you must *manually* create the *whole* `usage` text now.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an ugly hack (see my comment on the original question):

Define your own subclass of `HelpFormatter` to pass to the parser with the `formatter_class` option. The subclass should probably override the `_format_usage` method. This isn't entirely recommended, since the interface for defining your own formatting class was never made public.

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser, HelpFormatter
from gettext import gettext as _

class VersionedHelp(HelpFormatter):
    def _format_usage(self, usage, actions, groups, prefix=None):
        if prefix is None:
            prefix = _('Version: x.y\n\nusage: ')
        return HelpFormatter._format_usage(self, usage, actions, groups, prefix)

p = ArgumentParser(formatter_class=VersionedHelp)
p.parse_args()
```

Comment: I was writing the same thing, when I noticed that this naive solution doesn't work properly because the help starts with `usage:` anyway.

Comment: Old answer replaced with a completely different ugly hack :)

Comment: Thanks for that! I was going to try something similar and I don't think your hack was so ugly -- even if relies on an undocumented API. BTW, I've submitted an edit to include the explanation from your comment (which I hadn't seen until after I looked more carefully).

Answer (score 3):

A rough solution is to add the version text to your usage line.  It's not perfect (note the extra 'usage' text), but its a start

```
In [64]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(description='description')
# 'usage' parameter just sets the 'usage' attribute
In [67]: parser.usage='version 1.0.1\n'+parser.format_usage()
In [68]: parser.print_help()
usage: version 1.0.1
usage: ipython [-h]

description

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

The order of components in the `help` are determined by the `ArgumentParser.format_help` method (quoting from the `argparse.py` file):

```
def format_help(self):
    formatter = self._get_formatter()

    # usage
    formatter.add_usage(self.usage, self._actions,
                        self._mutually_exclusive_groups)

    # description
    formatter.add_text(self.description)

    # positionals, optionals and user-defined groups
    for action_group in self._action_groups:
        formatter.start_section(action_group.title)
        formatter.add_text(action_group.description)
        formatter.add_arguments(action_group._group_actions)
        formatter.end_section()

    # epilog
    formatter.add_text(self.epilog)

    # determine help from format above
    return formatter.format_help()
```

I can imagine writing a custom method that adds your version information, e.g.

```
def format_help(self):
    formatter = self._get_formatter()

    # version info
    formatter.add_text('version 1.0.1')

    # usage
    formatter.add_usage(self.usage, self._actions,
                        self._mutually_exclusive_groups)
    ...
```

In `ipython` this function works:

```
In [74]: def format_help(parser):
    formatter=parser._get_formatter()
    formatter.add_text('version 1.0.1')
    formatter.add_usage(parser.usage, parser._actions, parser._mutually_exclusive_groups)
    formatter.add_text(parser.description)
    return formatter.format_help()
In [75]: print format_help(parser)
version 1.0.1

usage: ipython [-h]

description
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution captures all stdout stderr output during parsing, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136611/capture-stdout-from-a-script).

On no input as well as on "-h,--help" it will print custom command, inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29293080/4062818) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4042452/4062818).

```
try:
    _out = io.StringIO()
    _err = io.StringIO()
    with redirect_stdout(_out):
        with redirect_stderr(_err):
            ARG = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:] or ['--help'])
except SystemExit as err:
    print("This program does something awesome but you got it wrong.")
    #possibly parser.print_help()
    sys.stderr.write(_err.getvalue())
    sys.stdout.write(_out.getvalue())
    sys.exit(err.code)
```