# Rearrange argparse groups in help text

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse

I have a rather complex CLI with `argparse` that has multiple sub parsers for different actions. For code legibility, I divided each action into one functions of which I only use one for this example:

```py
def _parse_args_one(
    subparsers: argparse._SubParsersAction,
    parent_parser: argparse.ArgumentParser,
):
    """Subparser for command one."""
    parser = subparsers.add_parser(
        "one",
        parents=[parent_parser],
        add_help=False,
        description="Command one descrpition",
    )
    group_required = parser.add_argument_group("Required")
    group_required.add_argument(
        "-i", "--input", type=str, required=True, help="Input help",
    )
    group_optional = parser.add_argument_group("Optional")
    group_optional.add_argument(
        "-o", "--output", type=str, help="Output help",
    )
```

For better legibility in the help text, I want to divide all arguments into the following groups:

- `Required`: All required arguments of the current action
- `Optional`: All optional arguments
- `Common`: Common arguments that are used in every action

I group all of them in the main / parent argument parser and have a rather strange `help` setup to not be shown in the top-level help-text:

```py
def parse_args():
    """Argument parser."""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        prog="customname", description="My custom CLI", add_help=False,
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "-h", "--help", action="help", default=argparse.SUPPRESS, help=argparse.SUPPRESS
    )

    parent_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
    group = parent_parser.add_argument_group("Common")
    group.add_argument(
        "-h",
        "--help",
        action="help",
        default=argparse.SUPPRESS,
        help="show this help message and exit",
    )
    group.add_argument(
        "-V",
        "--version",
        action="version",
        version="%(prog)s 0.0.1",
        help="show %(prog)s's version number and exit",
    )
    group.add_argument(
        "-v",
        "--verbose",
        action="store_true",
        help="set program output to verbose [default: quiet]",
    )

    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(title="Commands", dest="command")
    _parse_args_one(subparsers, parent_parser)

    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args
```

For the `main` help text I get the desired output:

```
usage: customname {one} ...

My custom CLI

Commands:
  {one}
```

Unfortunately, for the `action` help text I have the `Common` group listed first and not as desired last:

```
usage: customname one [-h] [-V] [-v] -i INPUT [-o OUTPUT]

Command one descrpition

# This should be last (after Required and Optional)
Common:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -V, --version         show customname one\'s version number and exit
  -v, --verbose         set program output to verbose [default: quiet]

Required:
  -i INPUT, --input INPUT
                        Input help

Optional:
  -o OUTPUT, --output OUTPUT
                        Output help
```

Is there a way to rearrange the order of these groups?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The help is created by `parser.format_help`.  You can  write your version if needed.  Note that it iterates on the `parser._action_groups` list.  So it's the order of groups in this list that determines the output.  Initially that list has 2 groups, the default 'positional' and 'optional'.  The rest are add in that they were created.

Comment: When using `parents`, groups from the parent are added first, when the (sub)parser is created.

Comment: Thanks for that. I saw you had a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22382568/python-argparse-print-usage-text-after-description). If you wan't to add a small answer I'd be more than happy to accept.