# Looking to set a global default argument with argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I am writting a new script and would like for the -h or --help argument to be called by default when the script is called without any parameters. So for example if someone calls `command_line_utility.py` then I want it to print the output you would get with `command_line_utility.py -h`.

I have dug around in the docs and looked at some examples, but all of them were specifying default argument values and not actually having arg parse call a default argument.

```py
# Setting up Main Argument Parser
    main_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="A set of python web utility scripts")
    main_parser.add_argument("-v",'--version', action='version', version='kuws V0.0.1')

    # Setting up the main subparser
    subparsers = main_parser.add_subparsers(help="Available commands found below, for more info on a command use: python command_line_utility.py <command> -h or kuws <command> -h")


    """Code below handles 'redirects' command in the main script
    i.e. >python command_line_utility.py redirects or kuws redirects
    """
    redirects_parser = subparsers.add_parser('redirects', argument_default='-u',
        help='Allows you to trace redirects and get other information')

    redirects_parser.add_argument('-u', "--url", 
        help='usage: python main.py redirects -u <url>; Lets you see the trace for a url', nargs='?', dest="trace_url")
```

As it stands when I run the file nothing actually gets printed to the command line. No help text or errors or anything.

Comment: Are you happy with the display when using the normal help command, the '-h' or '--help'?  I don't see what a global default has to do with displaying the help.

Comment: The command is going to be added to path and so for use ability I want the default to be -h so when people call the command they just see the help text instead of nothing. This is similar to how the git command works when you don't supply an argument.

Comment: Nothing in your `parser` is required, so it doesn't raise an error.  In older versions `subparsers` are required, now you have make that explicit.  Others have show you can display a full `help` it there aren't any command line values.

Comment: I don't think the `argument_default` parameter is doing anything useful for you.  Normally the default for an argument is `None`.  `argument_default` is just another way of changing that value (for all arguments of this subparser).  More often we use the `default` parameter in the `add_argument` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid `argparse` doesn't have any built-in support for this, but you can identify this situation and print the help message:

```py
import sys

if len(sys.argv)==1:
    parser.print_help(sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

When using subparsers, a common scheme is using `set_defaults(func=<function to be called>)` and then calling this function (as explained in [sub-commands](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands)).

You can simply define a first `set_defaults(func=help)` at first that will be overwritten with the functions of your command.

Note that you can also make the command required when you declare your `subparsers` (`add_subparsers(..., required='True')`) and thus, when the user invokes without a command, she will get an error with the usage.

Answer (score 0):

Checking that `len(sys.argv)==1` and in that case calling the `print_help` method of the parser as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042452/display-help-message-with-python-argparse-when-script-is-called-without-any-argu/4042861#4042861) to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042452/display-help-message-with-python-argparse-when-script-is-called-without-any-argu) is a possible way to print the help message defined in the parser when no arguments are given.