# Show subparser help and not main parser help when non-existent arguments used?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, argparse

I have a small CLI app (`myscript.py`) that is defined like so.

```py
import sys
import argparse

class MyParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    '''
    Overriden to show help on default.
    '''
    def error(self, message):
        print(f'error: {message}')
        self.print_help()
        sys.exit(2)

def myfunc(args):
    '''
    Some function.
    '''
    print(args.input_int**2)

def main():
    # Define Main Parser
    main_par = MyParser(
        prog='myapp',
        description='main help')

    # Define Command Parser
    cmd_par = main_par.add_subparsers(
        dest='command',
        required=True)

    # Add Subcommand Parser
    subcmd_par = cmd_par.add_parser(
        'subcmd',
        description='subcmd help')

    # Add Subcommand Argument
    subcmd_par.add_argument(
        '-i', '--input-int',
        type=int,
        help='some integer',
        required=True)

    # Add FromName Dispatcher
    subcmd_par.set_defaults(
        func=myfunc)

    # Parse Arguments
    args = main_par.parse_args()

    # Call Method
    args.func(args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The `MyParser` class simply overrides the `error()` method in `argparse.ArgumentParser` class to **[print help on error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636967/python-argparse-how-can-i-display-help-automatically-on-error)**.

When I execute

```py
$ python myscript.py
```

I see the default / main help. Expected.

When I execute

```py
$ python myscript.py subcmd
```

I see the `subcmd` help. Expected.

When I execute

```py
$ python myscript.py subcmd -i ClearlyWrongValue
```

I also see the `subcmd` help. Expected.

However, very annoyingly if I do the following

```py
$ python myscript.py subcmd -i 2 --non-existent-argument WhateverValue
```

I see the default / main help and not `subcmd` help.

What can I do, to ensure that this last case shows me the `subcmd` help and not the main help? I thought the subparser structure would automatically procure the help from `subcmd` as found in the third case, but it is not so? Why?

Comment: The `subcmd` parser puts the unrecognized strings in the namespace as `unrecognized`,  and returns control to the main parser for wrapping up.  It's the main that produces the 'unregcognized arguments' error.

Comment: To understand this behavior you/we have too look at the `argparse.py` code.  The documentation is not sufficiently detailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `unrecognized args` error is raised by `parse_args`

```
def parse_args(self, args=None, namespace=None):
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
    if argv:
        msg = _('unrecognized arguments: %s')
        self.error(msg % ' '.join(argv))
    return args
```

The subparser is called via the `cmd_par.__call__` with:

```
        subnamespace, arg_strings = parser.parse_known_args(arg_strings, None)
        for key, value in vars(subnamespace).items():
            setattr(namespace, key, value)

        if arg_strings:
            vars(namespace).setdefault(_UNRECOGNIZED_ARGS_ATTR, [])
            getattr(namespace, _UNRECOGNIZED_ARGS_ATTR).extend(arg_strings)
```

That is it is called with `parse_known_args`, and it's `extras` are returned to the main as `UNRECOGNIZED`.  So it's the `main` than handles these, not the subparser.

In the `$ python myscript.py subcmd -i ClearlyWrongValue` case, the subparser raises a `ArgumentError` which is caught and converted into a `self.error` call.

Similarly, the newish `exit_on_error` parameter handles this kind of `ArgumentError`, but does not handle the `urecognized` error.  There was some discussion of this in the bug/issues.

If you used `parse_known_args`, the `extras` would be `['--non-existent-argument', 'WhateverValue']`, without distinguishing which parser initially classified them as such.

Comment: Okay, so to clarify, I did override, the `parse_known_args` method in `MyParser` class (really the `ArgumentParser` class because of inheritance) and it solves the issue.